# How do I find latitude and longitude of each individual centroid in a grid cell

Tags: c#, gis

I plan to use google geolocator api for this. However, I want to create an application where anyone can create or insert a grid into this application, and when done, the application will recognize the latitude and longitude for each individual cell in the grid. Each grid cell will very in horizontal and vertical spacing and shape.

I plan to use C# primarily for this. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused by "grid cells" that vary in shape and spacing. Sounds like you're just trying to calculate the lat/long of a point on a sphere, which is weird since that's pretty much how you define such a point.

Comment: The application created has to automatically determine the centriod of each grid cell in any grid that is used with the application. The grid is a shapefile and the output file should be a shapefile that contains a number that identifies the grid cell of the random grid and the latitude and longitude of each grid cell centriod of the random grid the consumer used with the application. The application has to automatically recognize the number, latitude and longitude for any grid that is utilized with the application.